# Ordering by criteria - Using Recursive CTE

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have an sql table and I want to order it in the way that every element has the elements who have its code as `parentCode` in the rows directly beneath. To make it more clear take this example :

```
            id      name         code               parentCode

parent1      1      "element1"  "parent1code"       null
parent2      2      "element2"  "parent2code"       null
children1    3      "element3"  "children1code"    "parent1Code"
children2    4      "element4"  "children2code"    "parent2Code"
children3    5      "element5"  "children3code"    "parent1Code"
```

etc ..

and I want to order it this way :

```
  parent1    
   children1    
   children3 
 parent2   
   children2
```

***PS: there are non determined number of layers in this hierarchy (a child can be also a parent)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky in MySQL.  The basic idea is to build up a path to the top using a recursive CTE and then order by the path.  However, you want each identifier in the path to be of constant length to avoid ordering problems.  And, MySQL doesn't support arrays, so this all has to go into a string.

So, I would recommend something like this:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id, name, code, parent, 
             cast(lpad(id, 4, '0') as char(255)) as path
      from sample
      where parent is null 
      union all
      select s.id, s.name, s.code, s.parent, 
             concat(cte.path, '->', lpad(s.id, 4, '0'))
      from cte join
           sample s 
           on s.parent = cte.code
     )
select *
from cte
order by path;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=add786ae3f0004b44a030674eb8163a6) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This expands the ids to four characters.  That can easily be modified.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Recursive Common Table Expression` to achieve this

Try this:

```
with recursive cte(id, name, code, parent, key_) as (

select id, name, code, parent, array[id] as key_   
from sample where parent is null

union all
                                                                               
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.code, t1.parent, t2.key_ || t1.id 
from sample t1 
inner join cte t2 on t1.parent=t2.id
)

select id, name, code, parent from cte order by key_
```

[DEMO on Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/39txVMHgTjUY7Rjrw5vvNr/2)

**EDIT**

As per your comment details modified

```
with recursive cte(id, name, code,parent,key_) as (
select id,name,code,parent,array[code] as key_   from sample where parent is null
  union all
                                                                               
select t1.id,t1.name,t1.code,t1.parent,t2.key_ || t1.parent from sample t1 inner join cte t2 on t1.parent=t2.code
)

select id, name, code,parent from cte order by key_
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/39txVMHgTjUY7Rjrw5vvNr/3)

Comment: why is there numbers in the parent column ?

Comment: you can use what you want. ideally it must be the table id

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html). If you are new to CTE the below tutorials will help you to understand

https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-recursive-queries-in-postgres
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/